# How to reverse multiple patterns in sed?

Tags: sed

**test.sed:**

```
/^$\([a-z][a-z][a-z]\)$\([0-9][0-9][0-9]\)=\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\)/p
/^\+1$\([a-z][a-z][a-z]\)$\([0-9][0-9][0-9]\)=\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\)/p
/^1$\([a-z][a-z][a-z]\)$\([0-9][0-9][0-9]\)=\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\)/p
```

**file.txt:**

```
$abc$123=1234
1$abc$123=1234
11$abc$123=1234
+$abc$123=1234
++$abc$123=1234
+1$abc$123=1234
++11$abc$123=1234
```

**Command I used to run test.sed:**

```
sed -n -f test.sed file.txt
```

**Output:**

```
$abc$123=1234
1$abc$123=1234
+1$abc$123=1234
```

**Expected Output:**

```
11$abc$123=1234
+$abc$123=1234
++$abc$123=1234
++11$abc$123=1234
```

I have created `test.sed` that will grab any lines with 3 patterns and display them.

What I want to do is to reverse the output, like the way it is shown in expected output above that contains lines which current `test.sed` cannot grab.

How can I do this? I tried putting `/!p` instead of `/p` at the end of all 3 commands in test.sed, but it did not work properly due to many duplicates.

Comment: Change all the `p` to `d` and use `sed -f test.sed`?

Comment: why `$abc$123=1234` is missed from the expected output?

Comment: @BenjaminW. Thank you very much! that worked!

Comment: In the future, please don't torture us with a mile-wide regex, when any search-target (much, much shorter) could be used as your example. So please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inverse of

```
sed -n '/pattern/p' infile
```

is

```
sed '/pattern/d' infile
```

or, if your `/pattern/d` commands are in a separate file,

```
sed -f sedscr.sed infile
```

Notice that this exactly emulates what `grep -f` and `grep -vf` do: if your patterns are `pattern1` and `pattern2` then

```
$ cat sedscr1.sed
/pattern1/p
/pattern2/p
$ sed -n -f sedcsr1.sed infile
```

is the same as

```
$ cat grep_patterns
pattern1
pattern2
$ grep -f grep_patterns infile
```

and

```
$ cat sedscr2.sed
/pattern1/d
/pattern2/d
$ sed -f sedscr2.sed infile
```

has the same output as

```
grep -vf grep_patterns infile
```

(same file `grep_patterns`).